# How does one read data from a BLE device in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, event-receiver

My mobile phone app is supposed to be the central device and the BLE kit is supposed to be the peripheral device. I have managed to write to Kit, as in send data. The kit itself according to it documentation has this:
[image]

According to the documentation: The Rx (receive) and Tx (transmit) Characteristics are named from the point of view of the Peripheral BGX device.

To send a string to be received by the Peripheral serial interface, write to the Rx Characteristic.

To read a string transmitted from the Peripheral serial interface, enable Notifications or Indications from the Tx Characteristic then wait for subsequent Notification or Indication Events to occur.

So how exactly am I supposed to Read data from the device mentioned if the characteristic for receiving data doesn't have READ as one of its properties?

When I sent data as in writing data to the device I used the **writeCharacteristic** function.

```
  fun write(message:String){
    val bytes = BigInteger(message.replace("\\s".toRegex(), ""), 16).toByteArray()
    Timber.i("Bytes value ---> ${bytes.toHexString()}")
    val device = getBleDevice()
    val characteristicRX = getBleCharacteristic()
    writeCharacteristic(device, characteristicRX, bytes)
}
```

Then I would call this function to send:

```
fun sendMessage(message:String){
    Timber.i("Check if isConnected = true --> ${isConnected.value}")
    if(isConnected.value == true){
        write(message)
    }else{
       Timber.e("Make sure that you connected and paired with the desired device.")
    }
}
```

So how do I go on about receiving data instead from the BLE device? Wouldn't the readCharacteristic function come into play here? I ask this because the code I am working on was original designed to exchange data using classical Bluetooth and I was tasked with converting it into BLE instead. But when I used a serial monitor to see the bytes being sent I found that the buttons that are supposed to trigger receiving data are instead sending it to the Kit. This caught my attention as I haven't started working on the reading mechanism and the screenshot I posted here also has me puzzled, as I have thought that the **TX** characteristic would be a readable one not writeable.

In my app each parameter has a code. If it's a write command it looks like this:

```
  enum class WriteCommandCodes(val value: String) {
    TOOL_ADDRESS("08 00 00 00 20 30 04 27"),
    RPM_THRESHOLD("08 00 00 00 20 30 04 13"),
    BACKLASH_1("08 00 00 00 20 30 04 22"),
    BACKLASH_2("08 00 00 00 20 30 04 23"),
    DELAY("08 00 00 00 20 30 04 20"),

    BATTERY1_CAPACITY("08 00 00 00 20 30 0F"),
    BATTERY2_CAPACITY("08 00 00 00 20 30 10")}
```

the payload that is created later on has both the parameter's code and the data being sent.

for the Read parameters I have this:

```
 enum class ReadRequestCodes(val value: String) {
    KEY_ADDRESS("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 11 00 00 00 00 00"),
    TOOL_ADDRESS("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 27 00 00 00 00 00"),
    RPM_THRESHOLD("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 13 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BACKLASH("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 22 00 00 00 00 00"),

    POWER_SRC_TYPE("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 26 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BATTERY1_PERCENTAGE("08 00 00 00 20 30 11 00 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BATTERY2_PERCENTAGE("08 00 00 00 20 30 12 00 00 00 00 00 00")}
```

The same is supposed to happen only difference is I'll be receiving this time around.

Comment: Enable notifications and you will get a callback whenever the remote device has sent something.

Comment: enable them where exactly? In the onCharacteristicChanged override method?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you override the default onCharacteristicChanged method and implement what you want to do with the new data. You can see someone doing something similar here

[BLE receiving GATT notifications from a characteristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48810469/ble-receiving-gatt-notifications-from-a-characteristic)

Comment: yes but how does it work in my code? What I mean is after enabling notifications from a particular characteristic where do I receive the payload from the BLE device?